# Android - can't clip rect after rotation

Tags: android, canvas, drawable, android-custom-drawable

I'm trying to create custom drawable and in the draw(Canvas) function I use the methods: clipRect and rotate.
The clipRect working alone but if the rotate function ran before, the clipRect does nothing.

- It works on devices with android 6 and some of the devices with other android versions.